# How to run php files on netlify?

Tags: php, forms, netlify

I build a website which has a form. Contact form redirects to contact.php on submit. For some reason whenever I submit, it says page not found.

**index.html**

```
...
<form action="contact.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required><br>

  E-mail:<br>
  <input type="email" name="mail" class="form-control" required><br>

  Message:<br>
  <input type="text" name="comment" size="50"  class="form-control" required><br><br>

  <button type="submit" value="Send"> Send Message </button>
 </form>
 ...
```

**contact.php**

```
<?php

if($isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
$message = $_POST['comment'];

$mailTo = "sample@email.com";
$headers =  "From: ".$mailFrom;

mail($mailTo, $name, $message, $headers);

header("Location: index.html");
}
?>
```

I added a build.sh file containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
php contact.php
```

I also added ./build.sh in build command. I feel my script is wrong. Please suggest me alternatives to solve this problem.

Comment: You don't need any shell scripting commands. The web server will run all of the files for you. You need to make sure that the file is correctly named, and that it's looking in the correct folder on your web server.

Comment: @aynber Filenames are correct and contact.php resides in root directory.

Comment: Let's see your form

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya added HTML code.

Comment: So, your `index.html` and `contact.php` are in the same directory, yes?

Comment: yes @ChukwuemekaInya

Comment: See my answer. If you are trying to submit a form to a `.php` page on Netlify, the page will not execute. There are no PHP services on a CDN deployed site. All the PHP must be built at the time of the deploy build and create static content.

Comment: @talves not the exact solution but it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A Netlify site is deployed to a CDN and serves up static content and although you can run PHP at the time of a deploy, you **cannot** execute PHP during a page request.

To submit a form, you can use [Netlify Forms](https://www.netlify.com/docs/form-handling/) or some other serverless forms solution.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using InfinityFree for hosting the PHP site for free. or if your need is just to send an email form and the rest is static pages then i recommend emailjs that will let you send emails for free. so that you can deploy your site in netlify or vercel

Answer (score -1):

You can use 000webhost.com hosting for uploading your php projects.