# Can I host a website on Netlify that includes a PHP contact form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, hosting

I know Netlify hosts only static websites. Do I have to find a different hosting service other than Netlify since I want to have a PHP contact form that customer will fill out and the info will be emailed back to me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can host website that including PHP files on Netlify [view this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52043325/5661396) and [watch this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6ElQ689HRcY) for more information about hosting PHP apps.

Answer (score 1):

use [form submit](https://formsubmit.co/) to receive emails. Watch [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/r4RQ38EoLds) on how to use it but the library is simple to use

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).