# PHP File not executing when my form is submitted

Tags: php

I created this contact.php file:

```
<?php
    $email_to = "culinaryshare@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = $_POST['Subject'];
    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $question = $_POST['Question'];
    $email_message = "Content: ".$question."\n\n";
    $email_message = "Sender Name: ".$name."\n\n";
    $email_message = "Sender Email: ".$email."\n\n";
    ?>
    <h1>Thank You For Signing Up!</h1>
    <p>Return to Our <a href="../index.html">Homepage</a></p>
```

Essentially, it gets it data from this form a user submits, then collects that data and sends it in an email to the address specified. This is my form code:

```
<form name="contact" method="post" action="contact.php">
              Name: <input name="Name" type="text" maxlength="50" required><br><br>
              Email: <input name="Email" type="email" required><br><br>
              Subject: <input name="Subject" required><br><br>
              Problem/Question/Feedback: <textarea minlength="3" name="Question"  placeholder="Insert Your Question Here (Ex: How Long Will It Take For My Recipe To Be Processed?)"
              style="width:90%;" required></textarea><br><br>
              <button data-mdb-ripple-color="rgb(222, 222, 222)" data-mdb-ripple-duration="300ms"
          data-mdb-ripple-centered="false" class="btn jumbo-btn  btn-rounded text-white"
          type="submit">
            Submit 
          </button>
          </form>
```

However, instead of doing this, when I submit the form, it will send me here:

[Where it will send me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pPB5.png)

I was expecting the php code to send an email to the email address, then redirect them to the .php page that contains the text code:

```
<h1>Thank You For Signing Up!</h1>
<p>Return to Our <a href="../index.html">Homepage</a></p>
```

This code is supposed to show the user to go back. Instead though, neither the message send function works, or the html page works.

Comment: How does your directory structure look?

Comment: you cannot execute PHP files in Netlify, that is why when I access you file directly it downloads it. there are plenty of other hosting providers for PHP. although most of them require some payment.
see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52043325/6330843